# How to perform action on JavaFX Chart axis drag?

Tags: java, javafx

How do I perform an action when the axis is dragged over?

```java
final CategoryAxis xAxis = new CategoryAxis();
final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis(1, 21, 0.1);
final LineChart<String, Number> lineChart = new LineChart<String, Number>(xAxis, yAxis);

// What should go in the ???
lineChart.getYAxis().getOnMouseDragged().handle(???)
```

Comment: You wouldn't call `getOnMouseDragged()`. You'd call `setOnMouseDragged(event -> {...})` and implement the behavior you want. Check out the documentation of [`MouseEvent`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/input/MouseEvent.html) for information on the different dragging gestures. Without more information on what you want to do, however, I'm not sure how to be of more help.

Comment: What exactly is your end goal? Do you want to handle a special chart-related action on your Y axis? Or just detect mouse dragging in a generic way (as you would for any JavaFX Node)?

Answer (score 0):

Simple, just missed the `setOnMouseDragged(event -> {...})` handler.